# Understanding why nrpe and mythtv services are running on localhost

Tags: macos, service, nmap

Out of curiosity I'll run `nmap localhost` periodically to see which ports are open on my host. A moment ago I ran this command and got the following output:

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-10-09 09:57 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00023s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5666/tcp filtered nrpe
6543/tcp filtered mythtv
```

Does anyone have any idea why nrpe and mythtv might be running on localhost? A second `nmap localhost` moments later returned on open ports, which all seems pretty sketchy to me. Any suggestions others have would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not open ports. The `STATE` column shows `filtered`, which means "prevented from communicating." This state often means a firewall is blocking traffic using those port numbers, but it can also mean that a probe or response was dropped and no response was received at all. This is most likely the case for you: the Nmap scan was too fast for your system at the moment you ran it and a probe was dropped. Since localhost scans are usually very reliable and fast, Nmap gets very aggressive in terms of short timeouts and few to no reattempts to determine a port's status.

Nmap is a great tool, but for checking listening ports on your local system it is usually better to use `netstat` (or `ss` on modern Linux systems). This queries the kernel directly to determine what processes are registered to receive traffic on each port, so unless you have been thoroughly hacked (rootkitted), it will always be more accurate than Nmap for local results. If you are going to use Nmap as a 2nd opinion, be sure to use the `-p -` option to check all 65535 ports, not only the 1000 most-frequently-used ones that it scans by default.

Comment: Spectacular answer. I wish I could upvote more! Thank you!